# calculate coordinates of a polygon using radius and centerpoint

Tags: math, geometry, polygon

I am trying to calculate the coordinates of a polygon, coding it out isn't really a problem, its just my maths is quite bad but slowly learning.

I need to calculate the coordinates based on the center point and radius. e.g. centerX = 40, centerY = 40, radius = 8, sides = 5, i = n 0 - 5

This is what I have so far.
    int x, y;
    int sides = 5;
    int angle = 0;

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sides; i++)
{
    x = round(centerX + radius * cos(2* PI * i / sides));
    y = round(centerY + radius * sin(2* PI * i / sides));
    points.push_back(point(x, y));
}
```

This does give me a nice polygon (kinda) when i plot the points on an online generator.

[image]

However, it is slightly rotated and i am not sure how to solve this, ideally i would like a flat line at the bottom.

So my questions are:

1. Is my formula for x/y correct? can it be improved?
2. how do i add rotation? for example 20 degrees

thank you for your help.

Comment: You probably want to use some non-integer type to hold the coordinates. For a radius of `8`, constraining coordinates to integers (/rounding) is quite a loss of accuracy. For a rotation, simply add the rotation shift in your formula for `x` and `y` within the loop; within `cos` and `sin`, respectively: e.g. `... * cos(2* PI * (i / sides + angle/360))`, given than `angle` is in degrees. But change your types into e.g. `double`:s first, though.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation is a matrix operation. In 2D it's [[cos(a),-sin(a)],[sin(a),cos(a)]] applied to each point (x,y) like so (I don't know your language):

```
 xnew= cos(a)* x - sin(a)* y; 
 ynew= sin(a)* x + cos(a)* y;
```

See e.g. [Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions) on Wikipedia.
Note that the angle `a` is in radians, so you might need to multiply by `pi/180` if your input is in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are coding in C++, I guess that what you are looking for is something like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sides; i++)
{
    double angle = M_PI / 2 + 2 * M_PI * i / sides;
    int x = round(centerX + radius * cos(angle));
    int y = round(centerY + radius * sin(angle));
    points.push_back(point(x, y));
}
```

Even if you choose to use integers to represent x,y coordinates it's better to use a `double` for the angle, which is in radians. I simply added Pi/2 to your formula to rotate the poligon 90° counter clock wise.